# How can I fix the size of parentheses around stacked function symbols?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, stacking-symbols

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I looked at a number of other questions regarding parentheses size but didn't find an answer to my problem.

I'm trying to stack two function symbols within parentheses.

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\LARGE(\mathrel{\substack{s\\ \\ f}})$

\end{document}
```

Which I would like to be rendered like this:

[image]

When I enter the MWE provided, though, it renders the parentheses a good bit smaller and much rounder than the image above (which was generated by entering `$\LARGE(\mathrel{\substack{s\\ \\ f}})$` at http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), with the result that both the "s" and "f" hang well above and below (respectively) the parentheses.

How can I get the MWE to match the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use font size commands in math mode, your input produces

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \LARGE invalid in math mode on input line 5.
```

In general `\left(...\right)` makes stretchy delimiters however you are loading `amsmath` which defines a command for this notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\tbinom{s}{f}$



\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Will accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: is the "empty" line in the middle relevant?  `\tbinom` doesn't include that ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton Nah, not really. That was just an artifact of my first attempt at getting it to look right (probably unnecessary even there; in fact, that was probably part of the problem). `\tbinom` is delivering the desired result.